# Find the Fourier series for $e^{-|x|}$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series

> Calculate the Fourier series for $e^{-|x|}$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$.

I know this function is even, there will no terms relate with $\sin$. To find $a_o$ and $a_k$, I need to calculate these two integrals 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-|x|}\,dx\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-|x|}\cos(kx)dx$$
My problem is I don't know how to integrate $e^{-|x|}$, can someone show me how to calculate that or give me a hint to start? Thanks

Comment: To calculate definite integrals of $f(|x|)$, simply divide the intervals into ranges where $x>0$ or $x<0$, replace $|x|$ with $x$ or $-x$ as appropriate, and carry on as usual. In your case, this is even easier -  since both integrands are even functions and the domain is symmetric you may simply replace $\int_{-\pi}^\pi$ by $2\int_{0}^\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already commented that these are even so rewrite your integrals as:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-x}\,dx\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-x}\cos(kx)dx$$

Evaluating these will give you:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left(1-e^{-\pi}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1-e^{-\pi}\cos(k\pi)+ke^{-\pi}\sin(k\pi)}{(1+k^2)\pi}$$